# How can I get a clojure webapp to automatically redeploy?

Tags: clojure, vaadin

I am developing a webapplication in Clojure and Vaadin, but I cannot get the application to autoredploy so that I just press refresh on the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you're using a REPL server that will allow you to load new Clojure code into your application at will.  In that case, it's just a matter of changing your workflow to:

1. notice problem
2. go to Clojure editor
3. Load new code into running application
4. Go to browser, hit refresh.

If you're using Maven, you can use the maven-jetty-plugin to automatically reload your webapp when you change its source files.  See [this post](http://cemerick.com/2010/01/08/sane-web-development-with-compojure-jetty-and-maven/) for more info.

Yet another options is to continuously attempt to reload your Clojure code.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
(defn reload
  ([] (reload #"."))
  ([ns-pattern]
    (doseq [ns (all-ns)
            :let [ns (.name ns)]
            :when (re-seq ns-pattern (str ns))]
      (require ns :reload))))
```

In whatever code you have that starts up your webapp, or in your main servlet init, etc., add something like:

```
(future (loop []
          (Thread/sleep 5000)
          (reload) ;; optionally specify a regex to match only your app's namespaces here
          (recur)))
```

Definitely not something you want to use in production.  I'd prefer using a proper remote REPL in every case, but the above will get you by.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work with Vaadin. Could you give more details please?

Comment: Hi, my apologies, this was my mistake in setup. Yes, the browser refresh works as long as I have "?restartApplication" at the end of the URL